# What kind of framework or tools to make Android and iOS App using XML (logic and layout)

Tags: android, ios, xml, mobile, mobile-development

I have a project from my developer, they make apps for me Android and iOS apps. When I check the source code they used Java code and they call file XML to load the data and all the logic is in the XML. This is the code structure:

`ProjectName`
`--and`*`keystore`

`--Android`

`--IOS`

`--plist`

`----common`

`----data`

`----html`

`----popover`

`----resource`

`----screen`

`----tr`

`----base`*`screen.xml`
`----finger.xml`
`----login.xml`
`----intro.xml`

This code was created in 2015 - 2016

My question is, what is the framework or tool to make this code? Cuz the developer didn't tell me. Please help

I think they used a hybrid framework to generate this project. Same as Flutter, React Native, Iconic, etc but they use XML so it's not Flutter, React native, and Iconic I guess.

Comment: Recalls distant memories ... Xamarin? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin

Comment: But the code is fully using XML for logic, some Java(native) code, and Objective C(native iOS) the code looks like:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/7dYo7pjZ

Comment: this is very old project, 2015-2016 and they also use AAR for some function @Blundell

Comment: Did you look up Xamarin? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin it uses XAML "Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) is a declarative language that's based on XML. "

Comment: Yes I did, but in my project, they used java and objective-c not C# code

Comment: mmm last punt: PhoneGap/Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Recalls distant memories ... Xamarin? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin

> Xamarin.Forms
> Introduced in Xamarin 3
> on May 28, 2014, and allows one to use portable controls subsets that
> are mapped to native controls of Android, iOS and Windows Phone.[36]
> Windows Phone was deprecated and removed in favour of UWP.
>
> It is also possible to target other different platforms such as Tizen
> (by Samsung), GTK (Linux), WPF and macOS even though they have stayed
> in Preview.
>
> **This system uses XAML.** Microsoft has modified this framework to work
> with the Universal Windows Platform.[37]
>
> Microsoft enables native mobile development with Blazor. Mobile Blazor
> Bindings allow developers to build native Android and iOS using C#,
> .NET, and web programming patterns.[38] Uno Platform also supports
> .NET-based native mobile development.[39]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-overview?view=vs-2022

> Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) is a declarative language that's based on XML. XAML is used extensively in the following types of applications to build user interfaces

Comment: The project is using XML and Java for Android, and iOS using XML and Objective-C, but Xamarin use C#. I think the project is not using Xamarin